# Map Existing Entity with Existing Table in Entity FrameWork

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

Is it possible to map existing tables with existing Entities in Entity frame work as like NHibernate doing.

For example. I have entity as

```
public class User
{
    public Int64 userId { set; get; }
    public String Username { set; get; }

    public Int64 RoleId { set; get; }
}

public class Role
{
    public Int64 roleId { set; get; }
    public String roleName { set; get; }
    public IList<User> listUser { set; get; }
}
```

I have Table as

```
Users with id,name,roleId
Roles with id,name.
```

Now I want to map both using XML files. Is it possible to map exiting tables with exiting Entities.

Comment: Why use XML files? Usual way of mapping in EF is data annotation attributes of fluent mapping

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1) Manage your mapping via the database first edmx file (see http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/database-first-development/creating-the-web-application)

2) Start with the database first approach then move over to a code first like approach using the fluent api (see http://agilenet.wordpress.com/2011/04/11/entity-framework-4-1-rc-with-an-existing-database/)

Answer (score 0):

Usual way of mapping in EF is data annotation attributes or fluent mapping (actually with NHibernate fluent mapping is also better, because it gives you compile-time checks). So, here is fluent mapping for your classes:

```
public class UserMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserMapping()
    {
        ToTable("Users"); // Not necessary, EF will use this mapping by default
        HasKey(u => u.userId);
        Property(u => u.userId).HasColumnName("id");
        Property(u => u.Username).HasColumnName("name");
        Property(u => u.RoleId).HasColumnName("roleId");
    }
}

public class RoleMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Role>
{
    public RoleMapping()
    {
        ToTable("Roles"); // Not necessary, EF will use this mapping by default
        HasKey(r => r.roleId);
        Property(r => r.roleId).HasColumnName("id");
        Property(r => r.roleName).HasColumnName("name");            

        HasMany(r => r.listUser)
            .WithRequired()
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.RoleId);
    }
}
```

Just provide these mappings to your DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserMapping());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RoleMapping());               

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

I suggest you to read MSDN article [Configuring/Mapping Properties and Types with the Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx).

Side note - another article to read is [Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), especially its Capitalization Styles part.